# Where can I find a high quality music library for python that plays OGG, ACC and/or MP3 which isn't pygame?

Tags: python, audio

I've tried the sound module in Pygame, and I haven't been satisfied with the results. I need to play music and sounds in my game. What can I use that works with OSX, Linux and Windows, and plays sound well? Unfortunately, pyMedia doesn't compile on OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/)** provides an object-oriented programming interface for developing games and other visually-rich applications for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux. Some of the features of pyglet are:

**No external dependencies or installation requirements.** For most application and game requirements, pyglet needs nothing else besides Python, simplifying distribution and installation.

**Take advantage of multiple windows and multi-monitor desktops.** pyglet allows you to use as many windows as you need, and is fully aware of multi-monitor setups for use with fullscreen games.

**Load images, sound, music and video in almost any format.** pyglet can optionally use AVbin to play back audio formats such as MP3, OGG/Vorbis and WMA, and video formats such as DivX, MPEG-2, H.264, WMV and Xvid.

Comment: Splendid!

This is brilliant. Thankyou. I have tested a sound and it plays brilliantly. I must now try to rid the program from pygame and GLUT and place this library into my program. 

I did see a mention about this library before but I never found anything to suggest it was suitable for my game.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently developed a high-level Python module which uses FFmpeg for decoding (i.e. it should support almost all existing file formats) and PortAudio for output: [`ffmpeg`](https://github.com/albertz/music-player/blob/master/ffmpeg.c)

A simple demo player is [here](https://github.com/albertz/music-player/blob/master/test_ffmpeg.py).

This was developed as part of a [music player project](http://albertz.github.com/music-player/). It has many high quality functionality such as audio volume normalization using an own ReplayGain algorithm, etc.